# Why does itertools.permutations() return a list, instead of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Why does itertools.permutations() return a list of characters or digits for each permutation, instead of just returning a string?

For example:

```
>>> print([x for x in itertools.permutations('1234')])
>>> [('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('1', '2', '4', '3'), ('1', '3', '2', '4') ... ]
```

Why doesn't it return this?

```
>>> ['1234', '1243', '1324' ... ]
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`itertools.permutations()` simply works this way.  It takes an arbitrary iterable as an argument, and always returns an iterator yielding tuples.  It doesn't (and shouldn't) special-case strings.  To get a list of strings, you can always join the tuples yourself:

```
list(map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234')))
```

Comment: Why are you using map over this when not a list comp, gen-expr, or other method.

Comment: I think `map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234'))` is sufficient. Adding the list() doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @BillCheng In Python 2, the result of `map()` already is a list, that's true, but this question was about Python 3.  In most cases, you should be able to make do with the generator object returned by `map()` in Python 3, but for easier testing I added the explicit conversion to a list.

Answer (score 16):

Because it expects an iterable as a parameter and doesn't know, it's a string. The parameter is described in the docs.

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 3):

Perumatation can be done for strings and list also, below is the example..

```
x = [1,2,3]
```

if you need to do permutation the above list

```
print(list(itertools.permutations(x, 2)))

# the above code will give the below..
# [(1,2),(1,3),(2,1)(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried, but most likely should work

```
comb = itertools.permutations("1234",4)
for x in comb: 
  ''.join(x)
```