# Itertools.permutations returns <object> instead of list of permutations

Tags: python, list, permutation, python-itertools

When I input:

```
import itertools
perm = itertools.permutations(List)
```

I get:

```
<itertools.permutations object at 0x03042630>
```

instead of my permutations list. Could anybody help me to get the actual list that contains all permutations?

Comment: This is an iterator object. What you can do is to iterate on it using for loop like: `for p in perm: print p`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Itertools.Permutations()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113684/python-itertools-permutations)

Comment: @Dataman Nopes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate through the permutations object you have to use a for loop:

```
import itertools
for permutation in itertools.permutations(L):
    print permutation
```

Answer (score 3):

It returns an iterator object. If you want to get the actual list, you can easily convert this iterator object in a list using `list`:

```
import itertools

l = [1, 2, 3]
perm = list(itertools.permutations(l))
```

gives you

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: thank you very much! I originally went with Coline's answer, although your solution worked as well. Thank you again for taking the time to help me. I am very new to programming!

Comment: Ok, for me it was not obvious that you just want to print all the permutations; I thought that you actually want to get all permutations in a list... Glad your problem is solved; keep hacking :)