# Why is the list appending the same element again and again?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I am trying to solve this problem of finding the permutation of a given list using the code below. But, the list, `final` keeps appending the same thing again and again. It should return `[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]` but instead it returns `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3], [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`. I have been trying to fix this for a while now and would really appreciate your help.

```
class Solution(object):
    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        self.final = []
        l = 0 
        r = len(nums) -1 
        self.permutation(nums, l, r)
        return self.final

    def permutation(self, nums, l, r):
        if l == r:
            self.final.append(nums)
            # print(nums)
            print(self.final)
        else:
            for i in range(r+1):
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
                self.permutation(nums, l+1, r)
                nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]

A = Solution()
A.permute(['1','2','3'])
```

Comment: I assume you can't use itertools? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113684/python-itertools-permutations

Comment: you change your list in-place instead of creating a new list every time. your final list contains references to the same list in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you change your list in-place instead of creating a new list every time. your final list contains references to the same list in the end.

a fix for that is to wrirte

```
def permutation(self, nums, l, r):
    if l == r:
        self.final.append(nums.copy())
        # instead of self.final.append(nums)
```

note: [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) would do that job for you.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) might help understand what is going on here.

and as mentioned in the comment: you still do not get all the permutations. this might work for you:

```
def permutation(self, nums, k):
    r = [[]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in nums for b in r if a not in b]
    self.final = r
```

Comment: That being said, the code still does not accomplish the desired task