# Calculate products of columns according to combinations with replacement

Tags: python, matlab, loops, combinations, combinatorics

## The Problem

It's a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best. I know the equation to find the number of combinations with replacement. Let's say I have 6 vectors: A, B, C, D, E, F. If I want to find every possible cubic product of these 6 variables, it would be (6+3-1)!/3!(6-1)! = 56 combinations (see end). Similarly, if I want every quadratic product, it's 21. For just linear, of course 6 (just each variable itself). I want to calculate all 6+21+56 = 83 combinations. I am thinking of 3 loops and each inner loop starts iterating from its outer loop like

```
for i1=1:6
   X(:,?) = X.*X(:,i1)
   for i2=i1:6
      X(:,?) = X.*X(:,i2)
      for i3=i2:6
         X(:,?) = X.*X(:,i3)
```

But the index of the 83-column matrix to store all the data in the left-hand side is confusing me. They are marked with question marks as you can see.

PS: Might need to do this with 5th order too so it would add another 126 and 252 columns for a total of 461 columns. So a more generic code is better that doesn't hard-code 3rd order. But if it's hard-coded to 5th that's OK since I am definitely not going above that.

Either MATLAB or Python is fine since I can switch easily between both.

### The quadratic combinations calculated with an example

Here is an example of the 21 columns I expect for the quadratic combinations of the 6 variables, A through F. Done in Excel. I have taken 3 samples for each vector.
[image]

### The cubic combinations list

Here are the 56 combinations I need to calculate:

A,A,A

A,A,B

A,A,C

A,A,D

A,A,E

A,A,F

A,B,B

A,B,C

A,B,D

A,B,E

A,B,F

A,C,C

A,C,D

A,C,E

A,C,F

A,D,D

A,D,E

A,D,F

A,E,E

A,E,F

A,F,F

B,B,B

B,B,C

B,B,D

B,B,E

B,B,F

B,C,C

B,C,D

B,C,E

B,C,F

B,D,D

B,D,E

B,D,F

B,E,E

B,E,F

B,F,F

C,C,C

C,C,D

C,C,E

C,C,F

C,D,D

C,D,E

C,D,F

C,E,E

C,E,F

C,F,F

D,D,D

D,D,E

D,D,F

D,E,E

D,E,F

D,F,F

E,E,E

E,E,F

E,F,F

F,F,F

Comment: Why is ``ABA``, ``ACA`` and so on not in the list ?

Comment: @Sushanth It is combinations, not permutations. So ABA and ACA are already counted in AAB and AAC.

Comment: In that case why not use the inbuilts, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33144821/4985099

Comment: I checked those tools before asking the question. They usually seem to work as/with lists and strings. I have never seen vectors or numbers being multiplied in combinations. I just tried it right now with my 6 vectors as the iterable input and 2 as the number of inputs to consider. I get 42 arrays so it's not right. I think it's finding something else, which also happens to be completely off..  `print(list(it.combinations_with_replacement([A,B,C,D,E,F], 2)))`

Comment: Can you add a small example with exact input and output, so we have a better idea what you want?

Comment: Also, are you okay with a solution in any of the two tagged languages?

Comment: @LuisMendo I have added an example with numbers and added that both MATLAB and Python are OK since I can switch between them easily.

Comment: What is the typical or maximum number of variables (6 in your example)? If it's not very large that may allow more time-efficient, vectorized approaches

Comment: @LuisMendo Probably 20-30 variables max. You already gave the vectorized approach so I guess that's not a problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vectorized approach in Matlab. It should be fast, but is not memory-efficient, because it generates all Cartesian tuples of coumn indices, and then only keeps those that are non-decreasing.

```matlab
x = [2 2 3 2 8 8; 5 1 7 9 4 4; 4 1 2 7 2 9]; % data
P = 2; % product order
ind = cell(1,P);
[ind{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(1:size(x,2)); % Cartesian power of column indices with order P
ind = reshape(cat(P+1, ind{:}), [], P); % 2D array where each Cartesian tuple is a row
ind = ind(all(diff(ind, [], 2)>=0, 2), :); % keep only non-decreasing rows
result = prod(reshape(x(:,ind.'), size(x,1), P, []), 2); % apply index into data. This
% creates an intermediate 3D array. Compute products
result = permute(result, [1 3 2]); % convert to 2D array
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't care much about memory right now since I won't be using it on super large data. At best, 20-30 vectors maybe, in which case I will probably reduce the order. Now I will just try to migrate this to Python. Looks like standard functions so I think it should be easy. What does the permute do and is the [1 3 2] specific to order 2 or works with any order?

Comment: `permute` changes the order of dimensions (not their associated sizes). It's a generalization of matrix transpose. Its second argument here is general, not just for the order 2 case. I _think_ its Numpy equivalent may be [`moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html), but I'm not fluent in Python/Numpy

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That makes sense. I will post the Python answer here if/when I get it working but this does the job perfectly, so I am very happy :)

Comment: @ZackFair I'm glad about that!

Comment: Hmm I just tried it for the 4th and 5th order and it seems to break down. I get, for 4th, 216 instead of 126 rows and the first 36 rows are the same, then every 6 columns are identical afterward. I expect 126 because of the combinations with replacement formula with n=6, k=4 gives (6+4-1)!/4!(6-1)! = 126. Is the fact that it produces a 3D matrix at one point limiting the code?

Actually, the problem seems to arise between lines 6 and 7 when the ind goes from 1296x4 to 216x4. I think the non-decreasing rows are not being enforce correctly.

Comment: OK I just investigated further and the problem is the `ind` matrix is kinda odd at the end of line 6. It's not the usual pattern of 1 for the first 36 rows, then the first 6 rows, then the first row and then repeating in the 3 columns as it is for P=3. The repetition pattern is definitely off. I have 252 rows of 1 in 1st column and things start to be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and repeat somewhere down the 2nd column. So Yeah that part is the problem.

Comment: Changed `cat(3` to `cat(P` and it seems to be working now. Seems the catenation works for any number including and up to that number so 3 was working for 1, 2, 3rd orders but not 4th, 5th. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackFair You are right, it should be `P` (or anything larger than that) rather than `3`. Thanks for catching that! Edited. I've changed to `P+1` rather than `P` because I think it's clearer that way (stack all the  `P`-dim arrays along the next dim)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid confusion of indexing by using a counter:

```
clear all; close all

% Original matrix
M = [
   2 2 3 2 8 8;
   5 1 7 9 4 4;
   4 1 2 7 2 9
];

% Number of combinations
order = 3;
sizeX = nchoosek(size(M,2)+order-1,order);

% Combinations
imat = ones(sizeX,order);
for c=2:sizeX
    imat(c,:) = imat(c-1,:);
    for o=order:-1:1
        if (imat(c-1,o)<size(M,2))
            imat(c,o:end) = imat(c-1,o)+1;
            break
        end
    end
end

% Transpose & display combinations
imat = transpose(imat)

% Computations of products
X = ones(size(M,1),sizeX);
for o=1:order
    X = X.*M(:,imat(o,:));
end

% Display result
X
```

When you execute the script you get:

```
>> test_script
imat =
  Columns 1 through 16
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     4
     1     2     3     4     5     6     2     3     4     5     6     3     4     5     6     4
  Columns 17 through 32
     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     4     4     5     5     6     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     4     4
     5     6     5     6     6     2     3     4     5     6     3     4     5     6     4     5
  Columns 33 through 48
     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     4     4
     4     5     5     6     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     5     5     6     4     4
     6     5     6     6     3     4     5     6     4     5     6     5     6     6     4     5
  Columns 49 through 56
     4     4     4     4     5     5     5     6
     4     5     5     6     5     5     6     6
     6     5     6     6     5     6     6     6

X =
  Columns 1 through 16
     8     8    12     8    32    32     8    12     8    32    32    18    12    48    48     8
   125    25   175   225   100   100     5    35    45    20    20   245   315   140   140   405
    64    16    32   112    32   144     4     8    28     8    36    16    56    16    72   196
  Columns 17 through 32
    32    32   128   128   128     8    12     8    32    32    18    12    48    48     8    32
   180   180    80    80    80     1     7     9     4     4    49    63    28    28    81    36
    56   252    16    72   324     1     2     7     2     9     4    14     4    18    49    14
  Columns 33 through 48
    32   128   128   128    27    18    72    72    12    48    48   192   192   192     8    32
    36    16    16    16   343   441   196   196   567   252   252   112   112   112   729   324
    63     4    18    81     8    28     8    36    98    28   126     8    36   162   343    98
  Columns 49 through 56
    32   128   128   128   512   512   512   512
   324   144   144   144    64    64    64    64
   441    28   126   567     8    36   162   729
```

I tested it for `order=4` and it should work.

Comment: I think there may be some small mistake here because the last 4 rows (EEE, EEF, EFF, FFF) should have first two rows as 512, 64, and then 8, 36, 162, 729, respectively, which I am getting when I use Luis' code below. That's why I chose that as the correct answer, since it's also general to any order. But thanks still!

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what's wrong `2^3=8`, `5^3=125` and `4^3=64` no mistake. Maybe I didn't understand your problem or your comment. Looks like you found a solution to your problem so that the main thing ;)

Comment: So you have EEE and FFF which are 8^3, 4^3, and either 2^3 or 9^3. So the 512, 64, 8 and 512, 64, 729 columns 53 and 56 in your answer. They're OK. But EEF and EFF should have 2*2*9 = 36 and 2*9*9 = 162 in the last row (with 512, 64 in first & second rows).

Comment: You are right my bad. I used the example code without paying too much attention to the results. All the multiplications must be done inside the three FOR loops. I edited the answer thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks so much for fixing it! This is a bit slower than the other but, as I have tested now on 4th and higher orders, works for them. I just replaced your number of combinations part with a single line since it's an explicit expression from combinatorics: (n+k-1)!/k!(n-1)! I will try to use the other if it's fixed because it is more generic and can do different orders without changing the for loop (here I will need to copy-paste the code 5 times if I want all 5 order combinations). But I will definitely use it until then and progress with my work!

Comment: Yes the matrix form is faster for sure. I tried to respect your original code given that you were confused with indexing I didn't want to completely change your solution. I haven't understood that the order as a parameter. I'll edit the code for you.

Comment: It should do the job now whatever the original matrix and order. For this problem the computation is not really heavy the memory consumption is probably the big deal. Good luck for the next!