# Python - how to set limit of chars in result of permutation?

Tags: python, string, char, permutation, limit

I found [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) how to do permutation of some chars in python. But I add to string other chars and now when I run the code I see combinations with **long of 26 chars**.
I would like to create combinations **from all chars** of string to **only 10 chars**.
Where may I rewrite it?
Thank you

```
def toString(List): 
    return ''.join(List) 
  

def permute(a, l, r): 
    if l==r: 
        print (toString(a))
    else: 
        for i in range(l,r+1): 
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 
            permute(a, l+1, r) 
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] # backtrack 
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
n = len(string) 
a = list(string) 
permute(a, 0, n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import permutations  

p = permutations(string, 10)
```

However, this will give you 5311735 results, which takes lots of time and memory.

---

UPDATE to get strings out:

```
from itertools import permutations
out = list(map("".join, permutations('abcde', 4)))
print(out)
```

https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/62935781

Comment: Only this:           ?                                                                                                       `from itertools import permutations 
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
p = permutations(string, 10) 
print(p)`

Comment: Yes, but it will never finish running, as there are far too many permutations.

Comment: I see at output: **<itertools.permutations object at 0x03BE90C0>**

Comment: Yes, the permutations object can just be printed, but it won't have been evaluated yet. To get anything useful you either have to use `list` to turn it into a list (takes a long time) or `map` to join them, like so:
`list(map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234')))`
See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113684/python-itertools-permutations

Comment: I run:
`from itertools import permutations 

list(map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234')))` Now I see    **list(map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234')))
builtins.NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined** but intertools was imported...

Comment: It depends on how you're importing itertools. In that code you are not importing itertools, but permutaions from itertools, which is different.

Comment: `from itertools import permutations 
import itertools
print(list(map("".join, itertools.permutations('1234'))))` Now it run´s but is isn´t expected result 1.) wanted to print results by one result (in cycle like firs posted code) - https://imgur.com/a/rCnBykg  2.) I wanted only limit results for 4 chars. I would like see this result: https://imgur.com/EOH1nnK. Need limit first code for 4 chars...